# Running Seq datalust in ACI with Caddy as a sidecar container for automatic https

Tags: azure, sequence, azure-container-instances, caddy

Used terraform to launch 2 containers. Caddy container works well but the Seq container will just Run for a few seconds and then get stuck at 'Waiting' and terminated state. If I change the Seq to another image such as Rabbit MQ, it works with no issue. What port should I put the Seq image in?

Here is my terraform setting for the seq container:

```
container {
  name   = "seq-aci-container"
  image  = "datalust/seq:latest"
    cpu    = "1"
    memory = "1"

    ports {
      port     = 5341
      protocol = "TCP"
    }


  volume {
      name                 = "seq-aci-data"
      mount_path           = "/data"
      storage_account_name = "seqacistorage"
      storage_account_key  = "<QUnGu7Iz+4R...c728qLY7+AStEEElJg==>"
      share_name           = "seq-aci-data"
    }

    environment_variables = {
  "ACCEPT_EULA" = "Y" 
  "SEQ_API_CANONICALURI" = "http://seq-aci-dns.eastus.azurecontainer.io/"
 
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Seq by default listens on port 80 for HTTP traffic and 5341 for ingestion over HTTP. If you're using Caddy as a reverse proxy to handle HTTPS, it's important to ensure that Caddy is correctly configured to forward HTTPS traffic to Seq's HTTP port.
If you're using Caddy for HTTPS termination, Seq should ideally be exposed on port 80. However, if you prefer to keep Seq on 5341, make sure Caddy is set to forward requests to Seq on this port.

Comment: The SEQ_API_CANONICALURI environment variable should reflect the external URL that clients will use to access Seq. If you're using Caddy for HTTPS, this should be an HTTPS URL.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Arko, and for the SEQ_API_CANONICALURI comment. It gave me an idea that I could be missing some environment variables too. Now, it all works well!

Comment: Glad to hear that, will post the same as answer for the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your Terraform configuration, you have set up the Seq container to expose port 5341. This is generally the default port for Seq's ingestion over HTTP, so it should be correct. However, based on my experience there are a few other factors to consider, to troubleshoot the problem.

First, check the logs of your Seq container for more details such as Waiting' or 'Terminated' state and associated error message.

Secondly, Seq, as a logging server, can be resource intensive. Based on your workload requirement ensure that the CPU and memory limits specified in your Terraform configuration are sufficient. The values you mentioned currently is (`cpu = "1"` and `memory = "1"`)

Finally, double-check the [environment variables](https://docs.datalust.co/docs/environment-variables) in your Terraform configuration for any missing environment variable in addition to *`SEQ_API_CANONICALURI`* such as  *`ACCEPT_EULA`*
If Seq stores data on a persistent volume, you might need environment variables to specify the paths. For example, *`SEQ_STORAGE_PATH`* then *`SEQ_LOG_LEVEL`* for Seq's internal logging.

```bash
environment_variables = {
    "ACCEPT_EULA"          = "Y"
    "SEQ_API_CANONICALURI" = "http://seq-aci-dns.eastus.azurecontainer.io/"
    // Add additional environment variables below
    "SEQ_STORAGE_PATH"     = "/path/to/seq/storage"  // Replace with the actual storage path, if different from default
    "SEQ_LOG_LEVEL"        = "Information"           // Adjust the log level as needed
    // Include other environment variables here as necessary
  }
```

Reference Documents:
[Seq setup](https://docs.datalust.co/docs/using-azure-container-instances-aci#:%7E:text=az%20container%20create,query%20ipAddress.fqdn)